# React Native - use a state variable in a static function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, static, state

I'm new to React-Native, I have a problem creating my app.
Basically, I have a main application that do things, one of those is setting a Date variable in state called: sleepTime.
I've created a clock that works perfectly and every seconds is updated.

My problem now is to create a function into my main application that compare the actual date (given from the clock) with the date saved before.

The problem is that I've used a static function which is called on every tick in the clock class, this function (`compareTime()`) is in the main class and obviously I get the "undefined is not an object" when I call it.

What I can't figure out is how to link the call made by clock with the date that I've saved before.

This is the static function:

```
static compareTime(){
  const sleepTime = this.state.sleepTime;
      if(new Date().toLocaleString() == sleepTime){
        this.stopTimer();
      }
 }
```

Clock class:

```
class Clock extends React.Component {
          constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
              time: new Date().toLocaleString()
            };
          }
          componentDidMount() {
            this.intervalID = setInterval(
              () => this.tick(),
              1000
            );
          }
          componentWillUnmount() {
            clearInterval(this.intervalID);
          }
          tick() {
            this.setState({
              time: new Date().toLocaleString()
            });
            MainPage.compareTime();
          }
          
          render() {
            return (
              <Text style={styles.greeting}>
                The time is: {this.state.time}
              </Text>
            );
          }
        }
```

And the return of the main render which is the only thing that links main and clock:

```
 return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Clock />
        <Text style={styles.greeting}>
            Sleep time: {sleepTime}.
        </Text>
      </View>
 )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **props** for that.
Since the  is a subcomponent of MainApplication, you can pass the function comparetime() to the  as props and this function can be called from within the

The main render would have,

```
<Clock compareTime={this.compareTime.bind(this)}/>
```

And the Clock class can use the function from props,

```
tick() {
  this.setState({
    time: new Date().toLocaleString()
  });
  this.props.compareTime();
}
```

You can also pass parameters if you want to get values from Clock class to Main.

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly!
I was tring to do it in this way but I was writing it in the wrong way.